# How to check user input Persian numbers character in form field with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check user input that is entering numbers in Persian or not. In the other words it's keyboard language is Persian or English.
The field accepts only number.
I'm trying something like this:

```
            document.getElementById("give_me_the_lang").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
            var patt = new RegExp("^[\u06F0-\u06F9]+$");
            if (patt.test(this.value)) {
                document.getElementById("show_lang_in_here").innerHTML = "Persian";                          
            } 
            else {
                 document.getElementById("show_lang_in_here").innerHTML = "english";
```

Comment: Can you add more details about what's not working?

Comment: @ecraig12345 I have posted the correct answer

Comment: in this case I think the persian characters are the same as english chars, only the system font (os font) is different.

Comment: NB: They should better be called Latin, not English.

Comment: @AminAdel .No . the code of English numbers is different from Persian numbers.

Comment: True, but FireFox (where Persian digits pose no problem) does not give any clue about the difference: the `value` property of an `input` with `type="number"` attribute will give the Latin string whether it is typed in Persian characters or not.

Comment: Firefox shows persian Numbers as Persian Numbers but when you click on increase or decrease rows in numbers field it converts it to Latin. @trincot

Comment: Yes, indeed. How does that relate to your question?

Answer (score 1):

In my code I have added a parameter to callback function and changed this.value to e.key. and it works correctly.

```
  document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        var patt = new RegExp("^[\u06F0-\u06F9]+$");
        if (patt.test(e.key)) 
            document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = "Persian";                            
        else 
            document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = "english";

             })
```

Second solution:

```
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
 if (isPersian(e.charCode))
   document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML='Persian';
 else
   document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML='English';

 });

function isPersian(charCode){
return (charCode >= 1776 && charCode <= 1785) 
}
```

[image: Unicode]

Comment: relying on which key is pressed is not reliable: input can be pasted in with keys or context menu, or dragged in with the mouse, or entered with another device...

Comment: Yes, we can use  a compound of different events like keypress , onchange or ... to handle it.but my issue was not events, the issue was how Can I test the user inputs